# Cannot find a way to monitor uninstallation of preinstalled Win10 Apps

Tags: windows, powershell

Currently working on automating the building of some images. I want to have it all documented and have a way to ensure nothing is ever skipped when an image needs created, updated, etc. It will save me a lot of headaches. Below is only the relevant code for this question

Part of uninstalling 'Preinstalled Win10 Apps' is not giving me what I am looking for.

I am not able to accurately see when an 'App' is truly uninstalled.

When it executes `Remove-AppxPackage` for an App, it will add a progress bar to the top of the PS Window showing its progress and when it completes. It disappears after a while, even if it does not show completed. It will continue to execute behind the scenes but I cannot tell when they are completed. Some are taking longer to uninstall than others.

My goal is find a way to monitor the removal. I cannot find anything built into `Remove-AppxPackage` for me to do that. I cannot find anything to check against.

I tried wrapping them in jobs using `Start-Job`, `Wait-Job`, `Remove-Job` but that didn't change anything. It was being marked as complete while the uninstall hadn't completed.

Any help or pointing me to a possible solution would be appreciated. Currently I either assume it is done after a lengthy period of time or I rerun the code to see if it tries to process the uninstall.

Testing on a clean install of Win10 Build 1709

**List of Apps I am wanting to remove**

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Win10_Apps_To_Uninstall = @(
    "Microsoft.BingWeather"
    "Microsoft.GetHelp"
    "Microsoft.Getstarted"
    "Microsoft.Microsoft3DViewer"
    "Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub"
    "Microsoft.MicrosoftSolitaireCollection"
    "Microsoft.Office.OneNote"
    "Microsoft.OneConnect"
    "Microsoft.People"
    "Microsoft.Print3D"
    "Microsoft.SkypeApp"
    "Microsoft.Wallet"
    "microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps"
    "Microsoft.WindowsFeedbackHub"
    "Microsoft.XboxApp"
    "Microsoft.XboxGameOverlay"
    "Microsoft.XboxIdentityProvider"
    "Microsoft.XboxSpeechToTextOverlay"
    "Microsoft.ZuneMusic"
    "Microsoft.ZuneVideo"
)
```

**Code to loop through the removal and unprovisioning**

```
foreach ($Win10_App in $Win10_Apps_To_Uninstall) {
    try {
        Get-AppxPackage -Name $Win10_App -AllUsers | Remove-AppxPackage -Verbose
    }
    catch {
    }    
    try {
        Get-AppXProvisionedPackage -Online |
            Where-Object DisplayName -EQ $Win10_App |
            Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -Verbose | Out-Null
    }
    catch {
    }
}
```

Comment: Once you execute the script, and it returns back to the PS prompt, how do you know that it is still "executing" behind the scenes, and is not complete yet? i.e. once you get back to the prompt, it is done.

Comment: You can just add another loop to check if they still exist: if (Get-AppxPackage -Name $Win10_App ) {

Comment: @HAL9256 The only indication that I have that it isn't complete is when I go to verify it manually that it is uninstalled by rerunning the loop for the uninstalls. I have noticed it will try to process it again if it not completely uninstalled. Eventually it will not attempt an uninstall. I wish I could find the step to check whether it is still processing or not.

Comment: @OwainEsau I am not sure that will work but I will be able to give it a try later on today when I do some more testing for other parts of my image building

Comment: I know that some apps may still seem installed until you do a reboot. I wonder if after the script finishes executing, you do a reboot, and then check again?